# How to change the contents of listview on item click?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview populated using a String array as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,res);
getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to change the contents of listview using OnItemClickListener.

Comment: you will get one list when you are calling getListView then write onItemClickListerner() For that then you can get position of the list item, after that you can change the code based on position.

Comment: Suppose at onClick i want to populate the list using a different array say arr1.What exactly do i write in OnItemClickListener?

Comment: Your question doesn't display any effort you've put in to solve your problem. Please research on your own for tutorials and code examples and come back with more detailed and specific questions.

Comment: Get the String array and create one more adapter and add that to new ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you want to make changes, do you want the user to make changes by giving input or you want to make changes through code directly. The following setOnItemClickListener set the new values to the variable. 
For taking input from the user, you need to populate it in the fragment or new activity, take the input from the user and commit those changes, refresh the list and show the updated data.

**Model class:**

```
public class Item {

    private String name = "";

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setItemName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void add(Item object) {
        itemList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> rList, Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        this.context = context;
        this.itemList = rList;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtItemName;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.itemList.size();
    }

    public Item getItem(int index) {
        return this.itemList.get(index);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            holder.txtItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        Item item = getItem(position);

        holder.txtItemName.setText(item.getItemName());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Activity class:**

```
public class ItemActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ItemAdapter itemListAdapter;
    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        itemListAdapter = new ItemAdapter(itemList, this);
        listView.setAdapter(itemListAdapter);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // add some items
        itemList.add(new Item("Charlie"));
        itemList.add(new Item("Jenny"));

        //add new items and changes to adapter
        itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                String beforeName = itemListAdapter.getItem(position).getItemName().toString();

                String changedName = "Thomas";
                itemListAdapter.getItem(position).setItemName(changedName);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to populate `listview` with different array then make a set get method in adapter view and set the array using set method in adapter then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` method. You would have a reference of adapter in `onItemClickListenr()` which you can use for calling and setting array.

Answer (score 0):

Really nice piece of work.
The onItemClickListener didn't work for me (android 8) until I added

```
itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after the change.